# How to restore an old Version of an UWP App?

Tags: uwp

I've got a backup of the corresponding App folders from `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\*App*` and I want to restore the old app or execute it somehow, because the company developing the app is continuously removing important features from the app.
I tried to just copy the folders back, but windows is really trying hard to prevent me. I simply cannot overwrite the files even as Administrator of the system.
Even windows backup, which was used to create the backup, is not able to restore the files properly due to missing write access.
I cannot simply execute the exe files from the backup, they complain about missing dlls.
This is all pretty frustrating...
Any ideas?

Comment: You must have permission from Trusted Installer or System to Edit Files

Comment: And how do I ask SYSTEM do give me access?

Comment: Go to the Folder then Right Click on it .. Open Properties then click on Security Tab then Click Advanced then you will see owner is system Or Trusted Installer then click change then then Write Your WINDOWS username then click ok then  ok then close See This image it may help you with STEPS : https://postimg.cc/gallery/9qd5Q3S/40a32181

Comment: This doesn't work for me :/ I've already taken ownership of the `WindowsApps` folder and of the folders belonging to the app (including all files below). I've also added my User with full access permissions to the app folders. When I try to overwrite/rename/delete a file within the apps folder I first get the UAC popup to confirm and then an error that I have to ask myself (my username) for access... The user `Administrator` also has full access. Edit: Also gave the group `Users` full access... no change

Comment: You must do this for the folder that contain you files not WindowsApps Folder .. Second : You must rename your foldet THAT contain your files to any other name (e.g Test) Then Restart .. Hopefully this works :)

Comment: I had to do this for the `WindowsApps` folder first, other wise I wasn't even able to browse it and look at the folders it contains. I've also taken ownership of the specific app folders. I'm not able to rename the specific app folder - it gets denied.

Comment: Sorry .. Great! .. You must get permission from WindowsApp Folder So Did you Restart :) .. If that did not work So your case is interesting :(

Comment: This is the Error .. You are getting Right https://i.postimg.cc/bNzGMnfK/Error.png

Comment: I got this error, except that it said my own username instead of SYSTEM. I hadn't done a restart since I was not able to rename the folder. I now did a restart, checked that my user was owner of all of the folders and also `Users` had full access... Now I was able to rename the folders and restore the backup (after killing the app in task manager). 
Thx so far. But now the App won't start. A window appears and closes within few ms if I try.

Comment: I am really Happy (As I said Restart your system) This problem Beacuse you deleted the folder manually So it still in other places in your system So I recommend to search for other places for the Folder to make sure it is completely deleted the Restart again then hopefully this will works :) .. To make sure this answer will help I will post as answer then you accept to help new people in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Beacause you don't have permission to access this folder So Follow this Steps :

1. Go to the Folder then Right Click on it
2. Open Properties then click on Security Tab then Click Advanced
3. Then you will see owner is system Or Trusted Installer
4. Then click change then then Write Your WINDOWS username
5. Then click Ok then Ok then Close The Window
6. Then Restart you System (Windows)

See This image it may help you with Steps : (https://postimg.cc/gallery/9qd5Q3S/40a32181)

Error : (https://postimg.cc/mh521tDw)

Comment: Thanks so far. This, in addition to giving `Users` full access on the folders, enabled me to rename the original folders (not their files though) and copy the backup back.
However, the app still won't start. ProcessMonitor tells me that it tries to load a `dll` from the same folder but read-access to the dll is denied and the process terminates. I gave full access to `Users` and `Everyone` but read-access to the dll is still denied.

Comment: @xsrf Make sure you gived yourself premession and Everyone Then Restart Too beacause it is Windows File (dll) I sure that will work

Comment: @xsrf Note : Delete the folder first and all sub files and Folders then restore you backup as it can ovewrite only your folder not sub files

Comment: Restart didn't help. I myself, Users and Everyone have full access to the folder (and the dll) but the app fails to load it. 
I don't really get why deleting the old folders (I renamed them) would help. Also I don't think I even can delete them since I'm still not even able to rename the files they contain.

Comment: @xsrf Did you do what I telled you above .. Deleting the Whole Folder then restore backup will help and the App will work .. But So Far you case is so interesting

Comment: No I didn't. I don't do stuff I don't understand. Instead I noticed that the old folders had given read access to an unknown user / SID. I used Power-Shell with Admin privileges and executed `Get-Acl AppFolder_renamed | Set-Acl AppFolder` to copy over all original ACLs. Now the UWP executes fine.

Comment: Kind of, but I messed up. The app started, but I noticed that the backup already was the same version. I found an older Backup, but it missed some assets. So I used the older backup together with the newer assets and hoped it would work. When the app started, it said "This app cannot run, please visit the windows store" and as soon as the Store opened my files got updated to the newest version. Now I don't know if the old version failed because Windows knew it was old, or because I missed to backup some assets. In any case, Windows detected it was old and updated it right away :/

Comment: So your app installed from Windows Store not from your Own (Created By You) Also I said before AppX Package Apps (AppX Package is the package of Apps on the Windows Store) .. Always be installed in a lot of places in the system not Just Windows Apps Folder So for that Windows detected it is old and must be updated as well .. :/

Comment: Of course this is not my app. Why would I complain about myself removing features from my app? The "the app is installed in a lot of places" makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: @xsrf I will simplify as much as I could .. Windows Store App installed in places in the System (Like the main files of app installed in Windows Apps Folder ) .. Other Files installed in different folder than Windows Apps Folder like a Folder in Background or hidden by default by Windows to protect Apps from Hcaking or Leacking the Source Code online That is at .. Even you didn't ask yourself How Windows detected that your app is Old and must be Updated Beacuse as Example there is JSON File called Version added in Windows App Folder and Other Places So you deleted The JSON file from

Comment: Windows Apps Folder but it is still in hidden Folder that also contain JSON File that called version so when you restored you backup windows is searching in the hidden folder that contain JSON File that called Version then it is compare Two Files Together so it will see the file that in Windows Apps Folder have version 1 and The file in Hidden Folder contain Version 2 .. So it will update App from Microsoft Store  .. That is it

Comment: I hope I helped you and Thank you so much Because your problem was really instersting and I Thank you again .. Wish you A Great Day :)